# Running and debugging Eclipse RCP as a Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho

Is it still possible to run and debug Eclipse RCP projects inside Eclipse after they were converted to a Maven project (for example with the help of Maven Tycho plugin). Does the conversion to a Maven project impact the Eclipse RCP project in this matter in any way? I would like to run the RCP application inside Eclipse without having to build it with Maven every time (it takes too much time).

I am familiar with Maven, but I don't know what impact it has to an Eclipse RCP application.

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tycho provides the headless build for existing PDE plugin projects.
You simply add pom.xml files to the projects. As far as PDE is concerned, these are still PDE plugin projects.

That means you can continue to use all the tools PDE provides, including Run/Debug launch configurations.